# Division with Complex numbers to get a + ib form: $ 1/(1 + i) $

Tags: complex-numbers

$ 1/(1+i) $

How does one go about this equation? I want it on $a + ib$ form, however I am lost. Is it as simple as just dividing $1$ with $1$ and then saying $+ i$? As in $ 1 + i $?

Comment: $\frac{1}{1+i}=\frac{1-i}{1^2+1^2}$

Comment: Is it equation?

Comment: I meant to write $ 1/(1+i) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume it's poorly written and that it should read
$$\frac{1}{1+i}.$$
In this case the standard technique is to use the equality
$$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{\bar{z}}{z\bar{z}}=\frac{\bar{z}}{|z|^2},$$
which automatically gives you 
$$\frac{1-i}{2}$$

Comment: Yeah, the format's a tad off. Couldn't get it right. But thanks.

Comment: Could you emphasize more on this technique? Where's the equality?

Comment: This is the equality I am referring to
$$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{\bar{z}}{z\bar{z}}=\frac{\bar{z}}{|z|^2}.$$
The equality is just a matter of definition, but its *stregth* relies on the fact that the denominator becomes a (positive) real number :)

Comment: Hmm, what exactly happens? As in could you go through it with the numbers and i? from experience I know it would help me understand.

Comment: Well: if $z=1+i$ just as in your case, $|z|^2=1^2+1^2=2$ and $\bar{z}=1-i$.

Comment: Hah thanks, I figured it out last night but thanks nonetheless :)

Answer (score 1):

$$z=\frac{1}{1+i}=\frac{1-i}{(1+i)(1-i)}=\frac{1-i}{1+1}=\frac{1-i}{2}.$$